# Add radio input in a XSL to display XML elements

Tags: xml, xslt, input, radio-button

I would like to display `<tags>` and `<text>` if radios buttons located in the xsl `<form>` are checked.

Here is my **xml**:

```
<global>
    <informations>
        <title>document 1</title>
        <text>This is text of doc 1</text>
        <tags>tag01</tags>
    </informations>
    <informations>
        <title>document 2</title>
        <text>This is text of doc 2</text>
        <tags>tag02</tags>
    </informations>
</global>
```

And here my **xsl** (with an HTML output method) :

```
<xsl:template match="/">

    <form><input type="radio">here</input><input type="radio">and here !</input></form>

    <xsl:for-each select="//informations">
    <div>
        <h2><xsl:value-of select="title"/></h2>
        <p><xsl:value-of select="text"/></p>
        <tag><xsl:value-of select="tags"/></tag>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Change

`<p><xsl:value-of select="text"/></p>`

To

`<p class="hideableText"><xsl:value-of select="text"/></p>`

Change

`<tag><xsl:value-of select="tags"/></tag>`

To

`<span class="hideableTags"><tag><xsl:value-of select="tags"/></tag></span>`

Your checkbox onClick must check the state of checkBox & hide or show the element.

Example (Using jQuery):

`$('p.hideableText').hide();`

`$('p.hideableText').show();`

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it's not really what I expected. My goal is to filter before the HTML output and jquery allow to hide/show after. I try a `<xsl:variable>` with a **checkbox** (when checked or not to hide/show) in the xsl but it seems to be difficult. Any idea?

Comment: This is simple. have the display style attribute of class `hideableText` as none by default so they won't be visible, then you can allow to show/hide by checkbox.